# How to how to work with char array in a Firebird UDF

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, firebird

`ib_util.h`

```c
#ifndef _IB_UTIL_H
#define _IB_UTIL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    extern void *ib_util_malloc(long);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif

#endif /* _IB_UTIL_H */
```

`test_udf.c`

```c
#include "ib_util.h"
#define MALLOC ib_util_malloc

typedef struct blob
{
    short (*blob_get_segment)();
    void *blob_handle;
    int blob_number_segments;
    int blob_max_segment;
    int blob_total_length;
    void (*blob_put_segment)();
} * BLOB;

char* fn_blob_echo(BLOB b)
{
    char *buffer = (char *)ib_util_malloc(256);
    return buffer;
}
```

compile to `.so`

```sh
FIREBIRD_UDF='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/firebird/3.0/UDF/';
NameFile='test_udf';
gcc -c -O -fpic -Wwrite-strings $NameFile'.c'; ld -G $NameFile'.o' -lm -lc -o $NameFile'.so';  sudo cp $NameFile'.so' $FIREBIRD_UDF
```

declare in firebird

```sql
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION fn_blob_echo
BLOB
RETURNS CSTRING (256) FREE_IT 
ENTRY_POINT 'fn_blob_echo' MODULE_NAME 'test_udf';
```

using

```sql
select fn_blob_echo(CAST('please run' AS blob)) from rdb$database;
```

ERROR

```
SQL Error [335544721] [08006]: Unable to complete network request to host "localhost". [SQLState:08006, ISC error code:335544721]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caZxw.png)

Comment: Please provide more details and ask an explicit question. I guess your UDF crashed the Firebird server, at a guess because you don't nul-terminate `buffer`. I recommend also asking your question on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support), as in my experience UDF development questions generally go unanswered here on SO.

Comment: Also, looking at the source of the UDFs in Firebird itself might be help, see https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/tree/B3_0_Release/src/extlib. Looking at some examples there suggest that a `CSTRING(256)` would require a char with size 257 (going by the [ascii_char UDF declaration](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/B3_0_Release/src/extlib/ib_udf.sql#L379) / [IB_UDF_ascii_char source](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/B3_0_Release/src/extlib/ib_udf.cpp#L73))

Comment: the error `Unable to complete network request to host` implies that you did not start TCP-listening firebird engine daemon. It has nothing to do with UDF, you do not have any server running to connect to. I also suggest you to look into Russian-language firebird forum at sql.ru

Comment: @Arioch'The Not necessarily, it can also mean that the connection was forcibly closed. Judging by the formatting of the exception message, the OP is using Jaybird to connect, and Jaybird will also use error 335544721 (isc_network_error) when it receives IO errors when reading or writing to the connection. A quick check of the Firebird sources suggest fbclient does the same, BTW.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yet still, how would it relate to UDF ? in my, maybe incomplete, mental image - all the SQL data processing, including UDF calls, happens "inside Y-valve", and the client code works above "Y-valve". So how could an error in UDF - short of instantaneous destruction of Firebird server process - trigger such an error in network code? And if UDF indeed crashed the server then there should be traces of it in OS and FB logs, plus it would be somewhat matching my idea of "you have no server running"

Comment: @Arioch'The If the UDF crashes the server, then there is no more network connection. The client will then notice that when it tries to send or receive communication from the server.